# Why is Visual Studio 2010 reading project files continously?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I turned process monitoring on and I noticed that vs 2010 doesn't stand still, it continuously reads the project files in the solution. Wtf?

I have this solution that progressively becomes slower and slower to the point where when I type in the C# editor the letters appear a few seconds later.

Below there is some info about the environment:

Is there anything I can do? And I am using TFS.

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
    Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
    Microsoft .NET Framework
    Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

    Installed Version: Ultimate

    Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Office Developer Tools

    Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

    Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual C# 2010

    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

    Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual F# 2010

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools

    UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker

    Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

    The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

    Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01019-532-2002102-70886
    Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

    CodeSmith Generator   5.3
    CodeSmith Tools Visual Studio Add-in Package

    Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
    Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

    Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2565057)   KB2565057
    This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
    If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
    For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057.

    IronPython Tools for Visual Studio   1.0
    IronPython Tools for Visual Studio provides intellisense, project support, project and item templates, as well as a REPL window for IronPython development.

    JetBrains ReSharper 6.0   Full Edition build 6.0.2202.688 on 2011-06-30T04:14:16
    JetBrains ReSharper 6.0 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2011 JetBrains, Inc.

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
    This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU.
    If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
    For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

    NuGet Package Manager   1.2.20325.9034
    NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://nuget.codeplex.com.

    RemObjects Everwood   3.0.17.265
    RemObjects Everwood for .NET
    Copyright 2003-2010 RemObjects Software, LLC. All rights reserved.
    http://www.remobjects.com/everwood

    Sybase PowerDesigner   Integration Package v15.3
    Sybase, Inc. PowerDesigner 15.3.0.3248 for Visual Studio (running v15.3.0.3248 Viewer)
    For support, please visit www.sybase.com\support

    tangible T4 Editor   1.0
    tangible T4 Text Template Editor - T4 Editor

    VisualStudioIntegration2010   1.0
    Information about my package

    .NET Reflector
    Visual Studio add-in that integrates .NET Reflector into Visual Studio to allow you to seamlessly debug into third-party code and assemblies, even if you don't have the source code for them.
    Visit www.red-gate.com for more information.
    Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Red Gate Software Inc.

    EntitySpaces - 2010
    EntitySpaces 2010
    http://www.entityspaces.net
    Persistence Layer and Business Objects for Microsoft .NET  
    Copyright (c) 2010 EntitySpaces, LLC
```

Comment: I get somewhat similar situation where it appears to be building a visual tree but it throws different error messages from you but then eventually clears all the errors.  SP1 helped a lot!  A reboot helps. And a multi-procesor helps (my problem) as then 1 CPU is at 100% but the other is free.

Comment: Disable the add-ons one by one until you find the troublemaker.

Answer (score 1):

After more usage, I noticed that it has to do with Resharper and running multiple instances of Visual Studio. As soon as I start having 3 or more instances vs2010 slows down. I also reported this issue to the Resharper folks.

Without resharper the ide was fast - I haven't tried though running multiple instances without resharper.

Since I love resharper I now use only one instance of vs 2010 and open others only when I need them and close them as soon as I don't need them.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue and use ReSharper