# Why is Visual Studio continuously calling QueryOpen on my csproj files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-io

I was trying to work out while compiles are taking so long, so I started “Process Monitor” and got a few unexpected results.

It shows that even when Visual Studio is not building it is continuously making the QueryOpen system call on each C# project file.   As we have about 100 project files in the solution is the considerable activity that I don’t understand the need for.

(I also have Reshaper installed, if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late, but I thought it still makes sense for others having the same problem:

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070937/why-is-visual-studio-2010-reading-project-files-continously). Obviously, Resharper might be the culprit if you have multiple VS instances running. However, I am having the same problem without Resharper... Might also be some other addon or VS itself.